# How to work with Media Picker in Umbraco 8?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I'm new to Umbraco and I'm trying to use media picker on my site but for some reason the value is always null or empty.

I followed the steps in [here](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Fundamentals/Backoffice/Property-Editors/Built-in-Property-Editors/Media-Picker/) but when inspecting the html code i get the following results:

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="" style="background-image: url('')" alt="">
```

Here is my code:

```
@{
Layout = "Master.cshtml";
var image = Model.Value<IPublishedContent>("mainImage");

if (image != null)
{
<img class="img-fluid" src="@image.Url" style="background-image: url('@image')" alt="" />
}  }
```

In the Backoffice i added my image in Media first and i did click save and publish.
[backoffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMwId.png)

I'm running on version 8.14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are probably using the new (to 8.14+) media picker, you might need to do things a bit differently (like so: https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Fundamentals/Backoffice/Property-Editors/Built-in-Property-Editors/Media-Picker-3/ ) .

Answer (score 0):

I've had to reload models builder + recompile in order for it to trigger. Try giving that a go.